# AssertionError: verify response body as a test in postman

Tags: test-design, postman

This is the response from Postman:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "firstname": "tahaq",
            "lastname": "postmanq",
            "accountenabled": "true",
            "email": "tahaiq@hotmail.com",
            "phoneactive": true,
            "phonenumber": "+18738021112",
            "brandname": "kwikset",
            "emailnotification": true,
            "smsnotification": true,
            "pushnotification": true
        }
    ],
    "total": 1
}
```

Test in postman I am using:

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.test("Verify firstname", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData.firstname).is.to.equal("tahaq"); 
});
```

Error return as:

```
Verify firstname | AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 'tahaq'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to the above answer , in JSON {} is a JSON object and [] is an Json array.

So the JSON.parse just parses the response string into proper JSON. As the response starts with a {} you can access elements inside it as key-value.

hence , jsonData.data will give content inside '**data**' field. But now to access content inside data you have to use **index** as data is **json array** [].

And as there is only one json object {} in the array,  use  jsonData.data[0] means, the first JSON object in the jsonArray. Now again we have a **jsonObject** , so to get the field "**firstname**" we use:

```
jsonData.data[0].firstname
```

When ever you are in doubt in postman just print the content using console.log.

so just print :

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData);
```

The console output could be viewed in postman console which is under view> show postman console (or by pressing alt+ctrl+c) :

[image]

When you print it , you can JSON.parse prints the same response body :

[image]

so here we can see the structure like data>[0]>firstname:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this: `pm.expect(jsonData.firstname)`.

You left out `data` which is an array, so you need to write: `pm.expect(jsonData.data[0].firstname)` in order to find `firstname` in your json.

Answer (score 0):

you have an array, so do this

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.test("Verify firstname", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData[0].firstname).is.to.equal("tahaq"); 
});
```